# How to replace all white space from string usign JS

Tags: javascript

I have string :

> Test    Test Test   Test       Test

And I want to change it on Test-Test-Test-Test-Test

I've tried that

```
string= string.replace(/\s/g, "-");
```

But this code replace every white space and I get

> Test----Test-Test---Test-------Test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var str = "Test Test Test";
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: @Dawid77 glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be

```
var str = 'Test Test Test';
var replaced = str.split(' ').join('-');
console.log(replaced);
```